# How to enter rich text into tasks and activities?

Tags: activities

We use Salesforce to track all our sales communication using `Log a call` and creating tasks by this. We use shortnames to display the source of communication, f.e. skype for skype chat or fb for facebook chat.

However, when entering long chat logs or structured text, we would love to enter it as rich text into tasks and activity logs.

Is there a way to do so? The standard text field does only provide simple text.![enter image description here]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The only way I could think of was adding a custom field to activities where you could input rich text, however, when I tried to simulate the steps, I found that it doesn't seem to be possible, you can't add a custom field of type Text Area (Rich) to activities, the option just isn't available where you would normally find that type of field.

So my answer is, No, it is not possible.

There is an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000b1aPAAQ) for your question, if that could help (a little)

[image]

Comment: That Idea was merged into [another idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gde6rUAB/need-improved-html-email-capability), which is now closed; it was delivered as "Enhanced Email", which is the EmailMessage object.  It doesn't look like we'll ever get Rich Text on Task (Activity).